# limit of sequence ( proof )

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I want to prove, that $1$ is not a limit of sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \ \in \ \mathbb N$. ( I know that $\lim(\frac{1}{n})=0$ and I know how to prove it)

Definition of limit of sequence $(x_n)$ is: $\exists \ L \in \mathbb R$ such that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \ N \in \mathbb N$, such that if $\forall \ n \geq N$, then $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$.

Now I want to negate it so:

$L \ \textbf{is not}$ a limit of sequence $(x_n)$: $\forall \ L \in \ \mathbb R$, $\exists \epsilon>0$, such that $\forall \ N \in \mathbb N \ \exists \ n \geq N$,such that $|x_n-L| 
\geq \epsilon$.

So now to my problem. I have from my negation, that it's true for all $L \ \in \mathbb R$ and for all $n \ \in \ \mathbb N$, therefore I can take $L=1$ and $n=1$, and I can find $\epsilon>0$, such that $|x_n-L| \geq \epsilon$, now consider:

$\Big \lvert \frac{1}{n}-1 \Big \rvert= \Big \lvert \frac{1-n}{n} \Big \rvert=\Big \lvert \frac{1-1}{n} \Big \rvert=\Big \lvert \frac{0}{n} \Big \rvert=|0|=0$ $< \epsilon$, but it's not true since $\epsilon>0$. What is the problem here? I got that 1 is a limit of my sequence. Isn't it? I hope somebody can explain me it. Thank you!

Comment: Hint $\frac 1n\le\frac 12$ for $n\ge 2$ so what can say of $|1-\frac1n| $?

Comment: @zwim thank you for your answer. I think, that for all $n \geq 2$ it will work. So $|1-\frac{1}{n}| \ \geq \ \frac{1}{2} \ \forall \ n \geq 2$, right?

Comment: yes, sometimes a simple inequality answers the question at hand.

Comment: @zwim thank you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asserting that we don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=1$ means that there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for each $N\in\Bbb N$, there is some $n\geqslant N$ such that $\left|1-\frac1n\right|\geqslant\varepsilon$. In order to do this, take $\varepsilon=\frac12$. Then, for any $N\in\Bbb N$, if $n\geqslant$ and $n\ne1$, then $0<1-\frac1n\geqslant\frac12$, and therefore$$\left|1-\frac12\right|\geqslant\frac12=\varepsilon.$$

Concerning your approach, no, you *cannot* take $n=1$. For each $N\in\Bbb N$, you are supposed to look for some $n\geqslant N$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understood my mistake)

Comment: I am glad I could help.